# MVC3 Razor dynamic form creation and validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, razor

I have setup a page on my website where admin staff can create a competition and add any number of fields for certains types and they can be set to required or not to this competition.

When the competition page itself is loaded the questions load dynamically from the database using editor templates for each question type ie Text, Multi Select, Multi Line Text, Email

There are a few tables but the main ones are competition, CompetitionQuestions and QuestionTypes

Each competition can have multiple questions of different types.

The settings on the Question types have the validation type ie Email, RegularExpression, Length etc

and the Questions when added for each competition can be set as required or not

Now I can get my competition page to lead fine dynamically adding the questions for the page with an EditorFor and an Editor Template for each type.

My problem is I don't know how to manually apply validation for the required questions and the validation based on the question type validation settings?